# Truncated depth problem in depth images

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

Using a Python rendering script, I rendered `albedo`, `normal`, and `depth` images.

Below are example an `albedo` and corresponding `depth` image. I am not getting why depth is truncated at some moment. Could anyone please advise how I can get the depth of the entire object?

For the rendering script, I referred: https://github.com/panmari/stanford-shapenet-renderer.

[image: albedo]
[image: depth]

Comment: What format are you using for the depth images?

Comment: Yeah, that could potentially be an issue, if you are not using an HDR file format you are technically limited to 256 shades of grey for depth information

Comment: It saves the depth images as in PNG format now,

Answer (score 2):

This may be an issue with the render distance. Can you try extending the camera distance and see if this helps?

With the camera object selected, increase its End clipping distance in Properties > Camera settings > Lens:

[image]

Comment: I will try. But, please note that in my case, albedo and normal rendering is okay but only depth is problematic. can it still be the clipping problem? Plus, how can I control the clipping range in a python script?